# What mem cache implementation will take the least amount of effort to build

Tags: java, caching, lucene, redis, hazelcast

I am working on a web application, that will require some memory caching of potentially very large and changing data sets. My partners and I are starting to debate several solutions, but would like to gain some insight into what we can expect for a couple of different solutions. Our app is written in Java and will run under glassfish 3.1

1. redis and webdis
2. hazelcast
3. Apache JCS
4. Create our own with java

We are also considering apache solr or possible lucene alone (if we use hazelcast). Should we count solr as a memory cache solution, or is the solr cache not really comparable with the solutions listed above.

Thanks in advance for your recommendations

Answer (score 4):

It should be obvious that option 4 is definitely not the least effort.

I have had good results with Hazelcast. It provides a good return from minimal effort. Configuration is simple/straightforward, and the library as a whole "just works."

I am not familiar with redis or webdis.

---

You didn't include it in your list, but consider using [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) if what you really need is a *cache*.

Comment: Well we are not talking about rolling our own version of hazelcast, I meant creating our own simple object store. I would argue that after what it takes to learn a framework, it might be close, but that is why I am asking. I would also like to include JCS in the discussion. Forgot to list that one.

Comment: I'm also not familiar with JCS. I did find that Hazelcast and Ehcache are both very straightforward to get started with - not much of a learning curve. It would help if you could provide more specific/detailed requirements. (BTW, these are really more libraries than frameworks.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want simplicity, you won't much simpler than using a LinkedHashMap as a cache.

```
public static <K,V> Map<K,V> lruCache(final int maxSize) {
    return new LinkedHashMap<K,V>(maxSize*4/3, 0.75f, true) {
        @Override
        protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K,V> eldest) {
            return size() > maxSize;
        }
    };
}
```

The main disadvantage is that its very simple.

If you want it to be thread safe, use a Collections.synchronizedMap()

Comment: Thanks. We are looking for a distributed cache, so using a map or list is a bit too simple for our needs.

Comment: Why do you want a distributed system when you appear to have a small number of developers?  You can store many GB of data in a single instance.

Comment: Using a HashMap would prevent memory from being garbage collected. You could go with WeakHashMap, but it's not really a good idea for a cache. If you are going to suggest a Java implementation, go with the caches that are present in Guava.